# How to use Google Analytics Campaign on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-analytics

Hi I'm Android developer, and I met a challenge about using Google Analytics Campaign using SDK v4.x.

I have refered to the following URL

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

And I finished the step of 'Broadcasting an INSTALL_REFERRER Intent'
Because I could see this message successfully.

> Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
>   cmp=com.example.analyticsecommtest/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsReceiver
>   (has extras) }
>             Broadcast completed: result=0*

But I found this log :

> Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.

The reference URL said, the log means that my Google Play Campaign Measurement implementation is not working correctly. Thus I tried to fix the work as checking out troubleshooting section.

there are several reasons.

1. The INSTALL_REFERRER intent was not broadcast

   -> I finished it as I told
2. The Google Analytics Receiver did not receive the intent

   -> I implemented CampaignTracking correctly, I think.
   and only CampaignTrackingReceiver uses INSTALL_REFERRER.
3. Now, What can I do to implement CampaignTracking successfully?
4. and do I need to implement Receiver.class that extends BroadcastReceiver? (even I use SDK v4.x)
5. one more question, if I send setCampaignParamsFromUrl on my application code, what happen is going on?**

Here is AndroidManifast xml code.

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"

     android:enabled="true"

     android:exported="true">

         <intent-filter>

             <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />

         </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"

     android:enabled="true" />


    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"

         android:enabled="true"

         android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"

          android:enabled="true">

          <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />

          </intent-filter>

     </receiver>
```

please answer anyone who has used Google Analytics Campaign successfully.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243146/android-using-google-analytics-v4-campaign-measurement